# Can we host GAE applications on a Jboss server?

Tags: google-app-engine, jboss6.x

Can I host a GAE application (for example, "hello world") on a Jboss server? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think this is what you're looking for - http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf